# js modal box close function

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am using w3school modal method for modal box: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

One layer works just fine. I am trying to add one more layer on top of it as follow:

```
    <div id="modal" class="modal_class"><div class="modal_content"></div></div> 
    <div id="inner_modal" class="mc_innder"><div class="inner_modal_content"></div></div>
```

For example, let say I clicked the main button which shows the first modal box.

Within the modal box, there is another button that triggers one more layer on top of it.

Now, there are two layers (1st layer: z-index of 1 and 2nd layer with 2, so they are on top of each other).

The issue I am having is the closing function:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
 if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

Once the second layer is closed by clicking outside of the content (black background), then the click event is bound to the 2nd layer and 1st layer closing does not work.

I tried to create specific click function for two id's:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#modal', function (e) {
```

and

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#inner_modal', function (e) {
```

The issue is that, when I click the 2nd button (which is located inside of `#modal`), it closes the first layer and opens up the 2nd layer.

Would someone help me with how to get two layers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,

/*jc start edits*/
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close2 {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close2:hover,
.close2:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*jc end edits*/

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>


    <!--jc start edits-->
    <button id="myBtn2">Open # 2 Modal</button>
    <!--jc end edits-->
  </div>

</div>

<!--jc start edits-->
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal #2 content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close2">×</span>
    <p>Some other text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--jc end edits-->

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2'); // jc added

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");  // jc added

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];  // jc added

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block"; // jc added
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none"; // jc added
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none"; // jc added
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I just took the first step 3 "Try it yourself" sample and modified it.  Any line I added, I put a comment by so it will be easy to find.

For the record, w3schools teaches you some really bad stuff, and I wouldn't recommend you actually use this code.  For starters, you should separate concerns (javascript in one file, css in another, and html in yet another).  Also, this code isn't very scalable.  For every modal you add, you'll have to add a bunch of javascript.  You should write the functions to be reusable.

All in all, I recommend finding another site to learn from.